# Jquery and ajax open link and div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Welcome

How can I do to Jquery shown when you click the hidden div, and opened a link in a new window at the same time.

I am looking for an hour already and I can not find any project: (

Comment: How are you supposed to click a hidden div...?

Comment: I think he's saying he wants to show a hidden div when you click on something and also trigger a link at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any code samples this is the most specific I can be. Where `yourElement` is the id of the element you click on, and `hiddenDiv` is the div you want to show.

```
$('#yourElement').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenDiv').show();
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
});
```

If what you are clicking on is a link (a tag) you could do it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/otherLink"  id="yourId">Click here</a>

$('a#yourId').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $('#hiddenDiv').show();
      window.open(this.href, '_blank');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/

Comment: How can I dynamically change the link address, and text in a div.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question?

Comment: Of course, that you answered my question. Can this be solved in another way ... similar to that at http://www.netvouchercodes.co.uk/codes/flower-shows

Comment: podobny = similar. mowie po polsku : ) That page is doing exactly what my code is showing, showing a div, and opening in a new window. I only didnt show the markup. Edited my post.

Comment: W takim razie wielkie dzięki za przysługę :)

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check. and look at this too: http://jsfiddle.net/HCAfz/